Enum methods thread-safety
There is a notion that "singleton implementation of enum is thread-safe by default" which I found in this article at javatpoint.com.
If that is the case then does this mean that any method which I write myself inside of this enum singleton class is thread-safe as well without the need to use any additional keywords/logic to make it thread-safe?

Not a very helpful article, it goes on to show code that isn't thread-safe - getValue /setValue.

All of the named enum objects are guaranteed by the Java specification to be instantiated upon loading of the enum’s class file with no possibility of access or manipulation before the instantiation is completed, with no further instantiations during the rest of the execution of the app. This guaranteed behavior happens to be an ideal way to guarantee one, and only one, object is instantiated as a Singleton. And, conveniently, the code is brief, compact, and obvious to read. That is all that is going on; don’t read more into it than that.

No, that is not what it means. It just means that the creation and initialization of a singleton object by implementing it as an enum with one value is thread-safe, because of how class-loading works in Java. It means no more, and no less.
It does not mean that the implementation of your enum itself is somehow thread-safe if you don't program it in a way that is threadsafe.
